# Launch a batch file or a .exe from Selenium WebDriver

Tags: selenium-webdriver

I need to launch an executable, directly or by starting a batch file from selenium that will open a Browser application.
Anyone knows if Selenium WebDriver provides this capability. This question has been asked multiple times over the internet, but I did not find any promising solutions. 
Thanks.

Comment: Launching an application is nothing to do with Selenium. You do that in the language you are working with, not Selenium. As in, you launch a browser from C# or Java code, not Selenium code. Anyway, Selenium launches browser sessions for you - this is point of it. So expand on what you are trying to achieve and with what programming language.

Comment: The application I am trying to automate is Windows based running as a service. When the app is launched, it opens a browser session that is an abridged form of a browser with no url.

Comment: Continuing the above comment due to length limitation.I am using Java and Selenium RemoteWebDriver.I need to get control of that browser session and configure the required parameters. I am looking for a way to get handle of browser with selenium. Since Selenium will allow handle to the browser session that is initiated either by RemoteWebDriver or WebDriver, my idea was to launch the app from selenium API so that I can continue my configuration. The app can be launched by running the .exe with the url and can be started with a windows batch file.

Comment: I would like to get this working with Selenium as all my old automation runs wonderfully with Selenium WebDriver on FF/Chrome/IE. Any suggestion is welcome.

Answer (score 0):

Actually Selenium WebDriver do launch a browser and let you control it. There is many implementations of the WebDriver (for Chrome, Firefox, IE, etc.)

Anyway, I think you should tell us more about your problem.